# Scroll page when div appears with jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll

Right now I have a link that causes a hidden div to appear when you click on on it. However, the page itself doesn't scroll when the hidden div appears - so, unless the user *knows* to scroll down, they're not going to see the hidden div.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<p class="telephone2"><a href="#">Disclaimer</a></p>
    <div class="disclaimer">
      <p>Hidden div!</p>
   </div><!--end disclaimer -->
```

Here is my Javascript, which just calls Jquery:

// Drop down disclaimer

```
$(".telephone2").click(function () {
    if ($(".disclaimer").is(":hidden")) {
        $(".disclaimer").slideDown("slow");
    }
    return false;
});
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can use one of the many jQuery scroll plugins, it will scroll with little nice effect. you can change the hash to the div, there are a lot of ways.

Comment: I actually tried adding an anchor link and then having it scroll to the anchor link, but it seemed like there was some sort of problem in terms of what order it executed it in. Blah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go : working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/epinapala/xy2Ua/

```
<p class="telephone2"><a href="#">Disclaimer</a></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
    <div class="disclaimer">
      <p>Hidden div!</p>
   </div><!--end disclaimer -->

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(".disclaimer").hide();
    $(".telephone2").click(function () {
        if ($(".disclaimer").is(":hidden")) {
            $(".disclaimer").slideDown("slow",function(){
                var elem = $('.disclaimer');
        $(window).scrollTop(elem.offset().top);
            });

        }
        return false;
    });

​</script>
```

Comment: This fiddle thing is very cool! Beyond that, thank you for writing the code!

Comment: (It's not working on my site, however, which is frustrating.)

Comment: is your site public? so that i can take a look at the debugger to check whats wrong?
If you already got this working, then please ignore!

Comment: Yes sir! >>http://helenvholmes.com/hiznay/

The 'disclaimer' bit I was referring to in the question is at the very bottom of every page.

Comment: Kinda funny that it works fine when I downloaded the html page and clicked on disclaimer.  however i found a unrecognized character in your script.js. Can you try putting the contents of script.js in your html page at the bottom instead of a seperate file?

Comment: I found the problem. Goto your script.js. remove the extra line at the bottom, blank line num 11. so that your script would be now 10 lines. save and reopen your site-> click on disclaimer. I guess the unrecognized character on line number 11 is messing things!

Comment: Sure thing. I also just noticed that I have "#disclaimer" in the href, but when I take that out I'm getting other issues...

Comment: why do you want to remove #disclaimer form href? and what issues do you see when you see when you set href="#"

Comment: I was operating on firebug, changed your href to href="#" and removed an extra character from your Javascript &#8203; just before </script> and its working fine.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$(".telephone2").click(function () {
    if ($(".disclaimer").is(":hidden")) {
        $(".disclaimer").slideDown("slow");
        $(window).scrollTop($(".disclaimer").offset().top)
    }
    return false;
});
```